# rss feed shows article in future

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, rss

My rss feed, observatorulph.ro/rss.php shows all articles in the database, even if there are articles programmed to be published on a future date/time.

I want to make the rss extract just the articles that are older than the current date/time (let's say 20.05.2014 15:07:00, which is my time from the PC now).

Here's the actual syntax :

```
$azi  = date("Y-m-d");


$k = 0;
$cmd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_content WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(publish_up,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$azi') AND (state=1) ORDER BY publish_up DESC") OR DIE (mysql_error());
```

Comment: add `AND publish_up < NOW()` to the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Notting happened. I forgot to say that all my article feeds have +3 hours in the date/time field than the real date/time row in article database.